# Insert spaces in a string (Matlab)

Tags: string, matlab, space

I have a string

```
   S='ABACBADECAEF'
```

How can I insert a space in between each 2 characters in that string. The expexted output should be:

```
 Out_S= 'AB AC BA DE CA EF'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a few ways you can do that.  All of these methods assume that your string length is **even**.  If you had an odd amount of characters, then the last pair of characters can't be grouped into a pair and so any of the methods below will give you a dimension mismatch or out of bounds error.

---

## Method #1 - Split into cells then use `strjoin`

The first method is to decompose the string into individual cells, then join them via [`strjoin`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strjoin.html) with spaces:

```
Scell = mat2cell(S, 1, 2*ones(1,numel(S)/2));
Out_S = strjoin(Scell, ' ');
```

We get:

```
Out_S =

AB AC BA DE CA EF
```

## Method #2 - Regular Expressions

You can use regular expressions to count up exactly 2 characters per token, then insert a space at the end of each token, and trim out any white space at the end if there happen to be spaces at the end:

```
Out_S = strtrim(regexprep(S, '.{2}', '$0 '));
```

We get:

```
Out_S =

AB AC BA DE CA EF
```

## Method #3 - Reshaping adding an extra row of spaces and reshaping back

You can reshape your character matrix so that each pair of characters is a column, you would insert another row full of spaces, then reshape back.  We also trim out any unnecessary whitespace:

```
Sr = reshape(S, 2, []);
Sr(3,:) = 32*ones(1,size(Sr,2));
Out_S = strtrim(Sr(:).');
```

We get:

```
Out_S =

AB AC BA DE CA EF
```